# This recursive method to traverse a binary tree crashes after some recursions! Why?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, huffman-code

This is my class Node and `Traverse` is a method to visit an Huffman binary tree and save the codes of the characters of a .txt file. `Codes` is a vector of string where I save the codes. `Temp` is the temporary string where I save the character's code to put into Codes.

I don't understand why the first version of `Traverse` works great while the second one **crashes after some recursions.**

```
typedef class Node *NODE;

class Node { 
    private:
        int Key;
        NODE L;
        NODE R; 
    public:
        Node() { L = NULL; R = NULL};
        Node(int, NODE, NODE);
        ~Node() { delete L; delete R;};
        NODE Left();
        NODE Right();
        int GetKey();
        void SetKey(int);
        void Traverse(vector<string>, string)
        void Traverse(NODE, vector<string>, string)
};
```

First version:

```
void Node::Traverse(vector<string> &Codes, string Temp = "")
{
    if (L != NULL)
    {
        L->Traverse(Codes, Temp + "0");
        R->Traverse(Codes, Temp + "1");
    }
    else
    {
        Codes[Ch] = Temp;
        Temp.clear();
    }
}
```

Second version:

```
void Node::Traverse(NODE p, vector<string> &Codes, string Temp = "")
{
    if (p->Left() != NULL)
    {
        Traverse(p->Left(), Codes, Temp + "0");
        Traverse(p->Right(), Codes, Temp + "1");
    }
    else
    {
        Codes[p->GetChar()] = Temp;
        Temp.clear();
    }
}
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    // I Create the Huffman tree and save it's root into H_Tree pointer to Node.

    // It works great!
    H_Tree->Traverse(Codes, Temp);

    // It doesn't work!
    H_Tree->Traverse(H_Tree, Codes, Temp);
}
```

I trust in your answers.
Thank you.

**EDIT:** I have already tried to check if the right child is null but it always doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have callstack from crash? Do you know on which exact instruction it's crashing?

Answer (score 1):

in your second version you check the left node of the current node :

```
if (p->Left() != NULL)
```

and then you traverse both left and **right** nodes but you do not check if the right node is not `null` and for this right node the recursive call will check `p->Left` again but since p might be null (when you reach the tree leaves) the method will crash.

Comment: I Have already tried to check the right child but it always doesn't work. Your version crashes too.

In any case thank you a lot.

Comment: I removed my solution as I noticed that it may crash if Codes[p->GetChar()] is out of bounds. This will NOT throw an exception but might cause you to assign temp to a protected memory address which will probably crash your program

Comment: **I solve it!** In the `class Node` above I forgot to write the `Ch` member and its `GetChar()` method. `Ch` is an **unsigned char** while the method `GetChar()` returns a **char**, so in case of special characters, when I call `Codes[p->GetChar()]` it crashes!

Comment: I'd like to write an answer but I have to wait 8h.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are broken - you forget to check whether the right subtree is null before traversing it.

That the first version seems to work is just bad luck, and it *will* give you problems with some inputs.

Comment: I Have already tried to check the right child but it always doesn't work.

Comment: **I solve it!** In the `class Node` above I forgot to write the `Ch` member and its `GetChar()` method. `Ch` is an **unsigned char** while the method `GetChar()` returns a **char**, so in case of special characters, when I call `Codes[p->GetChar()]` it crashes!

I will write an answer when 8h will runs on.

Answer (score 0):

**I solve it!** In the `class Node` above I forgot to write the `Ch` member and its `GetChar()` method. `Ch` is an **unsigned char** while the method `GetChar()` returns a **char**, so in case of special characters `Codes[p->GetChar()]` crashes!